# Alarm Manager and gps service not stopping

Tags: android, gps, alarmmanager

I am new to android. I am using alarm manager. I want to stop the alarm manager and stop using GPSService when user press back button. I tried this but my app also runs in background. This is my code. Please help me

```
  public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv_latitude, tv_longitude;
private Toolbar toolbar;
GoogleMap map;
LatLng dest;
GPSService mGPSService;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Welcome");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    tv_latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    tv_longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity2.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    startAlarm();

    mGPSService = new GPSService(MainActivity2.this);
    mGPSService.getLocation();

    if (mGPSService.isLocationAvailable == false) {

        // Here you can ask the user to try again, using return; for that
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Your location is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

        // Or you can continue without getting the location, remove the return; above and uncomment the line given below
        // address = "Location not available";
    } else {

        // Getting location co-ordinates
        double latitude = mGPSService.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mGPSService.getLongitude();

        tv_longitude.setText("" + longitude);
        tv_latitude.setText("" + latitude);
        dest = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dest));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dest));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Log.e("Home back pressed", "called");
            mGPSService.closeGPS();
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent updateServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity2.this, 0, updateServiceIntent, 0);

            // Cancel alarms
            try {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            Log.e("Home back pressed end", "called");
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.e("back presed called", "clalles");
    mGPSService.closeGPS();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent updateServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity2.this, 0, updateServiceIntent, 0);

    // Cancel alarms
    try {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    Log.e("back presed endd", "clalles");
}

public void startAlarm() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    /* Repeating on every 20 minutes interval */
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0,
            10 * 60 * 20, pendingIntent);
    //   Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    // Other onResume() code here
    this.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("some_unique_name"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    // Other onPause() code here
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        double lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
        double longg = intent.getDoubleExtra("long", 0);
        tv_latitude.setText("" + lat);
        tv_longitude.setText("" + longg);
        Log.e("Broadcast Receiver lat", "" + lat);
        Log.e("Broadcast Receiver long", "" + longg);
        map.clear();

        dest = new LatLng(lat, longg);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dest));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dest));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
        //update the TextView
        // Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Settttttttt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
}
```

This is AlarmReceiver class

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
GPSService gps;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    updateYourActivity(context);
}

private void updateYourActivity(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent("some_unique_name");
    gps = new GPSService(context);
    gps.getLocation();

    if (gps.isLocationAvailable == false) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Your location is not available, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

    } else {
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        intent.putExtra("lat", latitude);
        intent.putExtra("long", longitude);

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I belive you are creating two instances of alarm manager. One in backpressed again which is the one you are cancelling. You need to be cancelling the instance you created in startAlarm() function

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu Thanks... and what about gpsservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                      MainActivity2.this, 0, updateServiceIntent, 0);
```

`PendingIntent.getService` method *Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a service*

But `AlarmReceiver` is extending `BroadcastReceiver` so need to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` to *Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast*

Like:

```
PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                          MainActivity2.this, 0, updateServiceIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but GPSService is not stopping.

Comment: @Priyanka: how you know `GPSService is not stopping` because you are not calling startService any where in code?